# remove /r /n from list and clear screen after timer

Tags: python, list, time

Im working on a simple program where the program reads a text file as a list and then displays the list in a grid style. I want to then display the list on screen, I have managed to do this but i keep getting /r/n at the end of each word. How do you remove the /r/n? Also if i wanted to clear rows a,b, and c before the next rows a, b, and d appear how would i clear the screen (is it an OS system CLS) or would you just print a loop for 50 blank lines?

Here is my program so far (not complete), i know there are probably much better ways but for me its a start, are there any better methods people would suggest to improve (be nice, I'm after improvement advice).

```
import time

print ('welcome to the missing word guessing game: ')
print ('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

menu = ('Menu \n 1. Easy game - press e \n 2. Hard game - press h \n 3. Quit - press q')
print (menu)
user_input = raw_input('Please type your response: ')

if user_input == 'e':
     file =open('words.txt', 'r')
     word_list = file.readlines()
     row_a = word_list [0:3]
     row_b = word_list [3:6]
     row_c = word_list [6:9]
     row_d = word_list [7:10]
     print (row_a)
     print (row_b)
    print (row_c)

print ('study the words')
time.sleep (5)
print ('Please wait - Do not touch any thing - just study')
time.sleep (5)
print ('Now study the words again, can you spot the word that is missing? ')

print (row_a)
print (row_b)
print (row_d)

user_answer = raw_input('Can you guess the word that is missing? ')
if user_answer == 'brown':
     print ('Well done')
     print (menu)
else:
     print ('Wrong answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all of the newline characters, just do:

```
word_list = file.read().splitlines()  # Instead of readlines()
```

And yes, to clear the screen I would just spawn a sub-process:

```
from subprocess import call 

call('cls', shell=True)
```

Comment: @P_Lee Are you sure? Files definitely have the attribute `read()`, and strings definitely have the attribute `splitlines()`. Make sure that you are using the exact code that I have posted.

Comment: @P_Lee And if you elaborate on where you are getting that error I might be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry if I down voted - didn't know that I had might be because on phone.

Comment: @P_Lee If you did downvote, I have edited the post so you can undo it- then we can talk about that `AttributeError`.